# createInvestment из книги Скотта Майерса Правило 18

Tags: c++

Что Майерс хотел сказать следующим кодом.

```
std::tr1::shared_ptr<Investment> createInvestment()
{
    std::tr1::shared_ptr<Investment> retVal(static_cast<Investment*>(0),
    getRidOfInvestment);
    ... // make retVal point to the 
        // correct object
   return retVal;
}
```

почему в retVal передается 0, и как потом перед return передать в retVal указатель.

Comment: теряюсь в догадках, что именно тут может смущать...

Comment: Что за книга и кого года издания?

Comment: Судя по тому что `shared_ptr` в `tr1` предположу, что книга старая и `nullptr` тогда не был в стандарте. В современном Си++ достаточно заместо `static_cast<Investment*>(0)` написать `nullptr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передаётся 0, т.к. реальный объект ещё не создан и если его не смогли создать, то вернётся shared_ptr указывающий на нулевой указазатель. Присвоить например так:

```
retVal = std::tr1::shared_ptr<Investment>(new InvestmentEx(), getRidOfInvestment);
```

Comment: не понятно зачем сначала создавать объект shared_ptr передавая ему нулевой указатель

Comment: Предположим у вас это фабричный метод, который в какой-то ситуции может просто не создать объект - закончилась память или другие условия, тогда вам необходимо вернуть нулевой объект.

Comment: если нужно вернуть shared_ptr содержащий нулевой объект тогда зачем при конструировании retVal передается указатель на функцию чистильщика.

Answer (score 1):

Этот пример показывает идею автоматической "подчистки". Функция createInvestment создает "инвестицию" (сущность). Но нужно не забыть её "закрыть" (удалить, завершить). Пока пользоватеть (программист) хранит возвращенный умный указатель, объект "инвестиция" живет. Когда указатель выйдет за пределы области видимости, автоматически будет вызвана функция "завершения".